# Makes user change Tkinter button if clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code:

```
def userChoice():
    text = "Clicked"


row1 = Button(root, text=" ", command = "userChoice")
row1.config(height="6", width="10")
row1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

I want to make it so that when the user clicks the button the text is changed. I am not sure how I would do this I ran this code and when the button is clicked nothing happens? I know this is a very simple question but just cannot figure out how to do it. I have been trying for the pas hour or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row1["text"]` to set new value:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def userChoice():
    row1["text"] = "CLICKED!"


row1 = Button(root, text=" ", command = userChoice)
row1.config(height="6", width="10")
row1.grid(row=0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Note: it serves no purpose to call both `row1.grid` and `row1.pack`. Use one or the other. In this case the call to `grid` is useless because it is overridden by `pack`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for you note! I did not notice this.